# how to find the most frequent character in a big string using java?

Tags: java, string, char

i'm working on an assignment that i have to find the most four  frequent characters  in a string.
i write this so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindTheMostOccur
{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      String input;
      String example = "how to find the most frequent character in a big string using    java?";

      String[] array = new String[example.length()];

      for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++)

      {
         int mostFrequent =0;

         for( int j = 0; j < example.length(); j++)
         {
            if(example.charAt(j) == i)
            {
               ++mostFrequent;
            }

         }

            System.out.println( (char)i + " is showing " + mostFrequent+ " times ");

      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output for this example.

**a is showing 5 times**

b is showing 1 times

c is showing 2 times

d is showing 1 times

e is showing 4 times

f is showing 2 times

g is showing 3 times

h is showing 3 times

**i is showing 5 times**

j is showing 1 times

k is showing 0 times

l is showing 0 times

m is showing 1 times

**n is showing 5 times**

o is showing 3 times

p is showing 0 times

q is showing 1 times

r is showing 4 times

s is showing 3 times

**t is showing 6 times**

u is showing 2 times

v is showing 1 times

w is showing 1 times

x is showing 0 times

y is showing 0 times

in this examle : t, a,i,n

I DON"T NEED SOMEONE TO COMPLETE THE PROGRAM FOR ME, however i need some ideas how to find the most four frequent character in this example.

Comment: _"i need some ideas"_ - Easiest way is to Use a `Map`

Comment: `Map<Character, Integer>`

Comment: I don't know how to use map + we are not supposed to use it.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: find the most four frequent characters in a string

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a Map? It's the only sensible way to store data like this.

Comment: Tim B : yeah, i think using Map and ArrayList will make it easy for me, but i have to use loops to find out the most four frequent char.

Comment: Create an int-array of size 26 (assuming only letters). Translate the just-analyzed char to its element index (`getIndexFromChar(c)`), then increment that array-element. Then you have to analyze the array for the highest number. (You can't use a map???)

Comment: how can i store all mostFrequent numbers into an array. so i can go through the array and find the most 4 frequent char

Comment: aliteralmind: where do i have to create that array? inside the second for loop or outside it.

Comment: They very first step. (Also, `getIndexFromChar(c)` must anticipate upper or lowercase).

Comment: i'm dealing just with lowercase, so i'm not worrying about uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest algorithm I can think of off hand is that instead of doing multiple passes do a single pass.

Create a `HashMap` mapping from character to count.

Each time you find a character if it is not in the map, add it with value 1. If it is in the map increment the count.

At the end of the loop your `HashMap` now contains the count for every character in the `String`.

Take the `EntrySet` from the `HashMap` and dump it into a `new ArrayList`.

Sort the `ArrayList` with a custom comparator that uses `entry.getValue()` to compare by.

The first (or last depending on the sort direction) values in the `ArrayList` will be the ones you want.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use HashMap or ArrayList in this problem

Comment: Then the problem is stupid. I'm sorry but it really is, they are the tools provided to solve exactly this problem and you would NEVER in a real world be asked to do anything like this without using them.

Comment: If the requirements are that ridiculous I'd probably just add an embedded Derby database, dump the data into a table in that and do a query for the top 4. The reaction you get to that might be...interesting... though

Comment: yes, they are very advanced tool to use. however, i"m still  beginner  in Java, and we didn't learn them yet.

Comment: @user3080461 Have you been taught how to create class and how to use them?

Comment: Rohit Jain: yes, why?

Comment: Why sort the ArrayList instead of just traversing it and finding the maximum value?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Because he wants multiple maximum values. There are some tricks you can do such as keeping the top x and scanning the list but the savings you gain are only significant if you have a small x and a really really big list, which is unlikely to be true in this case.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
int count[] = new int[1000];// all with zero
```

Then for each character from the string, do `count[]++` like this way

```
count['c']++;
count['A']++;
```

At the end, find out which index holds the maximum value. Then just print the `ascii` of that index.

Comment: Great idea. Even better is to do `count[Character.toLowercase(THECHAR)]`

Comment: 1000 seems overkill for 52 chars (in ASCII).  Use the number of options instead (based on the input).

Comment: `System.out.println(((char)i) + " occurs " + count[i] + " times")`---it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here're some ideas:

- To find the 4 most frequent characters, you must first know the frequency for all the characters. So, you would need to store the frequency somewhere. Currently, you are just printing the frequency of each character. You can't compare that way. So, you need a data structure.
- Here we are talking about mapping from a chararacter to its count. Possibly you need a *hash table*. Look out for the *hash table* implementation in Java. You will find `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `TreeMap`.
- Since you want the 4 most frequent characters, you need to order the characters by their frequency. Find out what kind of map stores the elements in sorted order. Note: You need to sort the map by values, not keys. And sort it in descending order, which is obvious.

**Using Array:**

- There is another approach you can follow. You can create an array of size `26`, assuming you only want to count frequency of alphabetic characters.

  ```
  int[] frequency = new int[26];
  ```
- Each index of that array correspond to the frequency of a single character. Iterate over the string, and increment the index corresponding to the current character by 1.
- You can do character to index mapping like this:

  ```
  int index = ch - 'a';
  ```

  So, for character `'a'`, the index will be `0`, for character `'b'`, index will be `1`, so on. You might also want to take care of *case sensitivity*.

Problem with the array approach is, once you sort the array to get 4 most frequent character, you've lost the character to index mapping. So, you would need to have some way to sort the indices along with the frequency at those indices. Yes you're right. You need another array here.

But, will having 2 arrays make your problem easy? No. Because it's difficult to sort 2 arrays in synchronization. So what to do? You can create a class storing *index* and *character*. Maintain an array of that class reference, of size `26`. Then find your way out to port the array approach to this array.

Comment: Don't forget upper case characters.

Answer (score 0):

What data structures are you allowed to use? 
I'm thinking that you can use a priority queue and increment the priority of the node containing the character that is being repeated. And when you are done, the first index would contain the node with the most repeated character

Answer (score 0):

I got another idea that you can do it using an array only. 
Well you have 26 letters in the Alphabet. The ASCII code of the lowercase letters range from 97 to 122(you can make every letter a lower case using .lowercase() or something similar). 
So for each character, get its ASCII code, do the ASCII code -97 and increment it. 
Simple,and only need an array.