# Designing a service to get most popular character at any given time from a streaming service

Tags: java, c#, string, rest, nosql

Designing a service to get most popular character at any given time from a streaming service

For example there is data streaming service which keeps giving list of characters. I need to design a service which will give the most popular character at any given time.

This is similar but need to implement this as a service

[how to find the most frequent character in a big string using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388576/how-to-find-the-most-frequent-character-in-a-big-string-using-java)

I was thinking of using nosql based db (dynamo) for storing the frequency map.
How do one go about handling overflows etc.

Comment: Can't you just keep some kind of counter on memory?

Comment: It depends on how big and how long this program will run. For long running, probably a database is a good choice. If just a temporary, then save it in a list in memory is enough.